# flutter intl Package Currency change according to localization

Tags: flutter, dart, localization, intl, currency-formatting

How to change the the currency value according to localization in intl flutter package. That is Dynamic and also changes the currency rate. For Example if localization is America then value should be $10 and if localization is Europe then currency should change to 9.09 eur etc. Any tutorial or anything that will guide me towards it. Implemented Language change using intl and arb file. Unable to find a solution for Currency change it only changes the symbol and not the currency rate